# Customising Search Box in Search Results Adding OnBlur and OnFocus Attributes

Tags: forms

I am trying to add custom #attributes to the search_form in the search results page. I get the $form_id from devel which is `$form_id = "search_form"`.

Here is my `hook_form_alter()` implementation:

```
function nm_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'search_form' ){
    $form['search-form']['#attributes']['onblur'] = "if (this.value == '') {this.value = '".$form['search-form']['#value']."';}";
    $form['search-form']['#attributes']['onfocus'] = "if (this.value == '".$form['search-form']['#value']."') {this.value = '';}";
  }
}
```

I checked if the condition is right inside the if statement with the following code, but nothing happened.

```
dpm($form['search-form'])
```

So, I am suspecting that the `if condition` is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add attributes to the form itself you need to do it on the `$form` array:

```
$form['#attributes']['onblur'] = "if (this.value == '') {this.value = '".$form['search-form']['#value']."';}";
```

I'm just guessing but I think you're expecting there to be a `search-form` element because that's the CSS ID of the form? That's not quite how it works with the FAPI, the elements are in a hierarchy that will eventually be rendered down to HTML. Until that rendering happens the elements have no concept of an ID/class etc., so you won't find them in the array under the ID/class.

Comment: Thanks, What I want to do was different that you answer, But thanks for guiding me. I finally did it. Will post the right way to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The [search form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_form/7) contains the following form elements.

```
  $form['module'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $module,
  );
  $form['basic'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
  );
  $form['basic']['keys'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => $prompt, 
    '#default_value' => $keys, 
    '#size' => $prompt ? 40 : 20, 
    '#maxlength' => 255,
  );
  // processed_keys is used to coordinate keyword passing between other forms
  // that hook into the basic search form.
  $form['basic']['processed_keys'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => '',
  );
  $form['basic']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
  );
```

There isn't any `$form['search-form']`.

If you want to add attributes to the form you need to add them to `$form['#attributes']`, as with the following code.

```
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-form';
```

If you want to add attributes to the textfield, then you should use `$form['basic']['keys']['#attributes']`.

Keep in mind that the attributes you add there are added to the search form, not to the page showing the search results. The page showing the search results is output from [search_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/search_view/7).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to add the onblur and onfocus to the input field not the form itself, anyway I did it after deeply looking for the array of the form. Will post the right way in the question. Thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

What I was trying to do was adding the onblur and onfocus attributes and here how I did it: You can insert the following to your template.php

```
function {ThemeName}_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'search_form' ){
    $form['basic']['keys']['#attributes']['onblur'] = "if (this.value == '') {this.value = '".$form['basic']['keys']['#default_value']."';}";
    $form['basic']['keys']['#attributes']['onfocus'] = "if (this.value == '".$form['basic']['keys']['#default_value']."') {this.value = '';}";
  }
}
```

*Thanks for all who helped.*